# Website is flagged as unsafe when shared using Facebook

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share content from my website,  http://www.banglanews24.com.

When I try to share any link from the website above in Facebook, it shows an error message like:

> "It looks like a link that you're sharing might be unsafe. Please
>   remove this
>   link: http://cdn.bn.banglanews24.com/media/files/june_2015/june_17"

My website does not contain unsafe content, it is in line with Facebook's terms and conditions. However, Facebook marks it as unsafe link.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook flags sites with this warning if they provide malformed metadata using the [Open Graph Protocol](https://ogp.me/).

To help pinpoint what content is causing Facebook to flag your page as unsafe, you can use the [Facebook Debugger Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808000138/https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object).

For http://www.banglanews24.com, the tool shows several warnings, any or all of which might be the root cause of your issue.

> **Inferred Property** The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided,
> even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> **Inferred Property** The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags. og:image
> could not be downloaded or is too small
>
> **og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough.** Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and
> use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from
> Facebook.
>
> **Share App ID Missing**  The 'fb:app_id' property should be explicitly provided, Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will
> be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in
> url when open the share dialog.

Answer (score -1):

in facebook its common problems.. facebook thinkd your website might br spam.. [related questions](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=761137663911368)

you keep an feedback to facebook

regards